# Is it even worth working a minimum wage job right now given the government's pandemic response?

Tags: canada, covid-19, employment-insurance

The work I was doing prior to COVID got shut down. I have since started a retail job that is close to minimum wage ($14.70/hr). I normally work 30-40 hours per week. Also I have some very part time work where they consider me a contractor, but this is unreliable.

Given the [CRB](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/benefits/recovery-benefit.html) is it even worth it to have a job that pays part time? If CRB gives everyone $1000 every 2 week that's almost as much as I make by working. My understanding is the CRB is only intended for people who aren't eligible for EI. Is it even worth working for minimum wage instead of collecting EI?

If I wasn't working I would be spending more time looking for a real job. Is any amount of paid work allowed when on CRB? If quitting my job helps, I'm still in my probation period if that makes a difference. The job I had before this one (which paid into EI) was above minimum.

Comment: Being not from Canada, but reading through the CRB eligibility rules, it looks to me that you’re eligible for the $1,000/week even if you’re working as long as the amount you’re earning now represents less than 50% of your pre-pandemic earnings.  It also doesn’t look like there’s an offset of the CRB based on a proportional loss of earnings.  But, also in the eligibility language is a requirement that you did not turn down work or voluntarily reduce your hours.

Comment: In the longer term, potential future employers might look upon you more favorably if your resume shows that you were working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get the benefit regardless, then working just puts more money in your pocket (~$600/wk). Would you like to have more money? Is it worth giving up your free time for? Only you can answer that question.

If they take away the benefit if you work for money, then nope, probably not worth it. But maybe - it could be good work experience that keeps you in the game so you can continue moving up. Hopefully $14.70/hr is not your long-term income goal.